# In History, Should the 'This Week' Button Show Since Monday/Sunday, or Last 7 Days

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, dates

I just noticed that the 'This Week' option under the summary of a user's activity pulls from the last Monday. While this makes sense, because technically it is 'this week', do you think it would be more useful if it pulled from the last 7 days? Especially if today is Monday, it would be pulling data from less than a day.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

Last 7 days for sure, or the first few days of the week will be worthless.

Who wants something that shows 7 times as much info one night as it did 6 nights before?

Where I live, Sunday is the first day of the week, not Monday. No need to internationalize if it's always the last 7 days.

Comment: Absolutely. Last 31 days, 7 days and Last 24 hours are a lot more useful than "This Month", "This Week" and "Last Week".

Answer (score 3):

What's worse it's not localized to your timezone, so depending where you are it could change in the middle of the day.